# Summation to a value n

Tags: javascript

I managed to write a code for a summation that is suppose to go to the integer 20 and it has the correct value of 210. However I am looking to get the value of each integer every time the program runs. So for the integer 1 it should say " The summation of 1 = 1" then the program will run again with a new line of text below the previous line saying "The summation of 2 = 3" etc. Right now all I can get it to say is "The summation of 20 = 210"

```
var summation = function(array){
    var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
    var currentSum = 0;
    var n = 0;
    var y = 30;
    
        for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
         currentSum += array[i];
         n ++ ;
         
        }   

fill(0, 0, 0);
textSize(12);
text("The summation of " + n + " = " + currentSum,30,y);

};

summation();
```

Comment: is this homework?

Comment: Move the logging inside the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing inside your function with the `for` loop is to first run the **whole loop**, setting `currentSum += array[i]` and `n++`.

Only after that you are calling `text("The summation of " + n + " = " + currentSum,30,y);`.

As MDN demonstrates:

```
let str = '';

for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  str = str + i;
}

console.log(str);
// expected output: "012345678"
```

So, if you want a new line of text each time the `for` loop runs, you need to set that **inside** the `for` loop.

```
var summation = function(array){
    var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
    var currentSum = 0;
    var n = 0;
    var y = 30;
    
        for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
         currentSum += array[i];
         n ++ ;
         fill(0, 0, 0);
         textSize(12);
         text("The summation of " + n + " = " + currentSum,30,y);
         
        }   
 

};

summation();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
var summation = function(array){
   var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
   let myStr = "";
   let current = 0;   
   for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
      myStr += `the summation of ${i+1} = ${array[i]+current} \n`;
      current = current + array[i];
   }   
   return myStr;
};

console.log(summation());
```